# Telerik Vb.net Autocomplete RadTextBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, autocomplete

I have a RadTextBox that stores the value into the Table(Comments) when the user enter a value. I want to use autocomplete property for this Textbox such that when the user tries to enter a comment he can get a lookup of those comments table to that textbox. Can anyone tell me the syntax or the proper way to use this. I went through few blogs but couldnt get correct information.

TextBox Syntax:

```
  <telerik:RadTextBox ID="CommentsTB1" runat="server" 
                     EmptyMessage="" MaxLength="200" 
                     Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="440px" Font-Bold="True" 
                     Font-Names="Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="#333333" AutoCompleteType="None">
                     <ClientEvents OnValueChanged="auditComments" />
                      </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through many blogs i came to know that 'AutoCompleteExtender' is not compatable with RadTextbox. So alternatively i used 'RadAutoCompleteBox' which resolved my solution

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="CommentsTB1" EmptyMessage="Please type here"
                                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Comments" InputType="Text" Width="350" DropDownWidth="150px" Delimiter=" ">
                                    </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```